# JavaScript Paper Scissors Stone - guide needed

Tags: javascript

Can anybody check the codes and let me know why it does not work properly for last line?

I am trying to compere the results from userChoice vs computerChoice but my last 'output' doesn't return any results. I think i should define variable 'output'? I am trying to take results from userChoice vs computerChoice and change into final text by using id=output.

```
//user choice
var paper = document.querySelector("#paper header");
paper.addEventListener("click", function() {
paper.classList.toggle("header-special");
userChoice = 'paper';
output.innerHTML = 'You  Chose Paper'
compareWithComputer('paper');
});

var scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors header");
scissors.addEventListener("click", function() {
scissors.classList.toggle("header-special");
userChoice = 'scissors';
output.innerHTML = 'You  Chose Scissors'
compareWithComputer('scissors');
});

var stone = document.querySelector("#stone header");
stone.addEventListener("click", function() {
stone.classList.toggle("header-special");
userChoice = 'stone';
output.innerHTML = 'You  Chose Stone';
compareWithComputer('stone');
});
```

// Computer choice

```
function compareWithComputer(userChoice) {
var computerChoice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
if (computerChoice == 1) {
computerChoice = "Stone";
} else if(computerChoice == 2) {
computerChoice = "Paper";
} else {
computerChoice = "Scissors";
}
output.innerHTML += '. Computer Chose ' + computerChoice;
}
// Compare userChoice and computerChoice
var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {
        if (choice1 === choice2) {
            return "It's a tie!";
        }
        if (choice1 === "stone") {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                // rock wins
                return "You win!";
            } else {
                // paper wins
                return "You lose! Try again.";
            }
        }
        if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "stone") {
                // paper wins
                return "You win!";
            } else {
                // scissors wins
                return "You lose! Try again.";
            }
        }
        if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "stone") {
                // rock wins
                return "You lose! Try again.";
            } else {
                // scissors wins
                return "You win!";
            }
        }
    };

   var results = compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
{
output.innerHTML = 'What is the result?' + results;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <div class ="start"
    <h1>Click the button, start the game!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="game" id="paper">
    <header>Paper</header>

    </div>
    <div class="game" id="scissors">
    <header>Scissors</header>

    </div>
    <div class="game" id="stone">
    <header>Stone</header>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: One thing you can do is make the random output a little simpler by doing something like Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1), which will then pick either 1, 2, or 3 randomly instead of having to mess with decimals.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your input! it's really great! i am a bit confused why did you put in the bracket (userChoice)? do I need to use it after my conditions will be used? and i am not sure if its all right i put in my function (userMove)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a function to call after a user selects Paper, Rock, or Scissors.  Put the "computerChoice" logic in this function to calculate the computer choice and compare it against what the user picked.

I added the function below but left the remaining portion for you to add the logic to compare the user choice and computer choice.

```
var paper = document.querySelector("#paper header");

paper.addEventListener("click", function(userMove) {
paper.classList.toggle("header-special");
userChoice = 'paper';
output.innerHTML = 'You  Chose Paper'
  compareWithComputer('paper');
});

var scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors header");
scissors.addEventListener("click", function(userMove) {
scissors.classList.toggle("header-special");
userChoice = 'scissors';
output.innerHTML = 'You  Chose Scissors'
  compareWithComputer('scissors');
});

var stone = document.querySelector("#stone header");
stone.addEventListener("click", function(userMove) {
stone.classList.toggle("header-special");

output.innerHTML = 'You  Chose Stone';
  compareWithComputer('stone');
});

// Computer choice
function compareWithComputer(userChoice) {
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "Stone";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "Paper";
} else {
 computerChoice = "Scissors";
}
  output.innerHTML += '. Computer Chose ' + computerChoice;

  // Enter conditional logic here to compare userChoice and Computer Choice

}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for suggestions! I added code to compare userChoice vs computerChoice but seems like 'output' doesn't work, can you have a look please( i already edited my code on the top)

Comment: In your updated code, you need to add the results of the compare function in your final output line (see below).  If this helped you, please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most.

output.innerHTML += '. Computer Chose ' + computerChoice + compare(userChoice, computerChoice);

Comment: Hi Daniel, still something wrong as I don't get any results: I added the following code to my lines of codes in order to get output: var results = compare(userChoice,computerChoice); { output.innerHTML += '. Computer Chose ' + computerChoice + compare(userChoice, computerChoice); }

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question, so I will not provide code however I will provide some pointers to help you.

I assume you are wanting the computer to make a random choice once you have clicked on a choice. You could wrap your `//Computer choice` section up into a function and call it after the user clicks a choice. You may wish to pass it the user's choice as a parameter which you could then use to compare against the computer's choice.

Answer (score 0):

To compare both selections, you want to have a `function` which does the comparison for you and gives you the result. But before you can write that, you have to assign a comparable value to each possible choices combination. In your case, what you need is called a hashmap/key-value-pair.

For example:

```
const CHOICES = {
  paper: { stone: 1, scissors: -1, paper: 0 }, // paper beats stone, but looses against scissors
  scissors: { paper: 1, stone: -1, scissors: 0 }, // scissors beat paper but loose against stone
  stone: { scissors: 1, paper: -1, stone: 0 }
};
```

With this, you can write yourself a function which takes both choices and compares them against this hashmap:

```
function compareChoices (user, computer) {
  const choiceValue = CHOICES[user][computer];
  return choiceValue > 0 ? 'user' :
         choiceValue < 0 ? 'computer' :
         /* otherwise */   'draw'; 
}
```

This allows you to determine the winner. For example:

```
var winner1 = compareChoices('stone', 'scissors');
// winner1 === 'user'

var winner2 = compareChoices('paper', 'scissors');
// winner2 === 'computer'

var winner3 = compareChoices('paper', 'paper');
// winner3 ==== 'draw'
```

Next, you need another function which regenerates the computer's choice. Otherwise, you can only play your game once without code duplication. You can use what you already have inside the body of the function:

```
function getComputerChoice () {
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
  return computerChoice < 0.34 ? 'stone' :
         computerChoice < 0.671 ? 'paper' :
         /* otherwise */          'scissors';
}
```

It is logically the same you did in your code already. The difference is, it allows you to *regenerate* a choice as many times as you need without *duplication of code*. Instead of `if`-statements, I used the ternary operator `condition ? truthy : falsy`, and instead of storing the choice in a variable, it *returns* the choice as a string which maps to the `CHOICES` mapping.

Call that function every time you need to generate a choice for the computer "player". Inside your event handler functions, you can now do something like this for example:

```
var paper = document.querySelector("#paper header");
paper.addEventListener("click", function(userMove) {
  paper.classList.toggle("header-special");
  output.innerHTML = 'You  Chose Paper'

  var computer = getComputerChoice();
  output.innerHTML += '<br>Computer has choosen ' + computer;

  var winner = compareChoices('paper', computer);
  if (winner === 'draw') {
    winner = 'nobody';
  }
  output.innerHTML += '<br><strong>The winner is: ' + winner + '</strong>';
});
```

**Further improvements**

This code can be enhanced in several ways. First of all, you could think about a way to write it less repetitive. Hint: Use the same technique we used to "extract" the essence of the `getComputerChoice` function from what you had already. Is there a way to abstract away the DOM querying and addition of eventlisteners?

It would be nice to have the UI *changing* instead of just displaying the winner. What I mean by that, is to *hide the choices `<div>` elements* from the user after he clicks, and display the result with a way for the user to play the next round.